# class_name foreign_key in Rails model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I recently come across this code. User has many Answer. What is the purpose of the :class_name and :foreign_key ?

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'Question", :foreign_key => 'question_id'
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The naming here is kind of strange, but the purpose of `:class_name` is to allow you to use a class that is different from the one Rails expects. When you have a `belongs_to :user` on a model, Rails would expect that to point to a parent class called `User`. In your example, Rails skips looking for a `User` class and instead looks to the `Question` model.

The most common usage of this, though, is when a non-default association name makes more sense than the default. So a more apt example is when you have a `User` model and `Competition` model wherein each competition has one user as a winner. You could have each `Competition` belong to a `User`, but that wouldn't be as expressive. Instead you may want to have the relationship be referred to as `winner`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :winners, class_name: "Competition", foreign_key: "competition_id"
end

class Competition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :winner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "winner_id"
end
```

This allows you to refer to users as `winners`:

```
competition = Competition.first
competition.winner
```

This is a lot more expressive than if you were to write `competition.user`.

Comment: Do you need to create those foreign keys in a migration, or is specifying them in the model enough?

Comment: @JamesLowrey Specifying them in the model here just assists ActiveRecord with the lookups. If you want the DB to properly constrain the foreign key, you need to add it to the migration as well.