# rails: using collection_check_boxes in each category

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:employee, :skill_ids, Skill.all, :id, :name) %>
```

on its own works just fine in my project. This way, each employee shows all skills and if they are checked or not.

Additionally to that, I have some categories, which the skills are related, to (Category has many Skills).

Can anyone recommend a proper way, to use the collection_check_boxes correctly for each category so only the skills related to the category are displayed? 
I think I am just missing the correct limitation for the "Skill.all" parameter.

Finally it should look like this, but instead of Submit buttons (by using jquery-ujs, method: put), I want those skills to be checkboxes.

http://d.pr/i/CYHaGH

Edit1: Skills and Categories model

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :subcategories, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "parent_id"
  belongs_to :topcategory, class_name: "Category"

  has_many :skills
end

class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employeeskillsets, foreign_key: "skill_id"
  has_many :employees, through: :employeeskillsets
  has_many :projectskillsets
  has_many :projects, through: :projectskillsets
  has_many :tagsets, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :tagsets

  belongs_to :category
end
```

Edit2: Still no progress. Does anybody have an idea how this could be done?

**SOLUTION:**

Ok, the solution was pretty simple. I just had to declare the collection on each category, which already was for a previous version of that app. <%= collection_check_boxes :employee, :skill_ids, category.skills, :id, :name%> (category.skills was set for each instance of categories).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution was pretty simple. I just had to declare the collection on each category, which already was for a previous version of that app. `<%= collection_check_boxes :employee, :skill_ids, category.skills, :id, :name%>` (category.skills was set for each instance of categories).

Answer (score 0):

Using `collection_check_boxes`, you can pass a block like that :

```
collection_check_boxes(:post, :author_ids, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial) do |b|
  b.label { b.check_box }
end
```

And you can access value, text and more :

```
collection_check_boxes(:post, :author_ids, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial) do |b|
   b.label(:"data-value" => b.value) { b.check_box + b.text }
end
```

You should read the documentation here :

https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes

You will find all you need to solve your issue,
Hope that help

Comment: That is what I've already checked. There is no indication (at least I don't see any), of how to use/change the "Author.all" to a smaller, scoped collection, so the categories (in my case) show only the related skills.

Comment: Do you try to replace `Skill.all` for `Category.skills` ?

Comment: Yes, I did but that doesn't seem to work. Undefined method "skills"

Comment: Could you edit your post with you models Skill and Category ?

Comment: Try : `category = Category.first` and : `category.skills`, I'm not sure, I use MongoDB in my projects, but I read this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132949/class-name-foreign-key-in-rails-model to understand how work your model

Comment: Doesn't work. This shows every existing skill on each category, just like using Skill.all. Guess I will try to use a scope but I am not sure if that will work the way it needs to be.